# Swift 2 count duplicate in array

Tags: arrays, swift, count, duplicates

Could you please help me to simplify the flow below?
the scope is to count how many time each element is duplicate within the given array.

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,9,3,3,9,9,9]

var testCount = [Int:Int]()

for curr in test {
    if let x = testCount[curr] {
        testCount[curr] = x  + 1
        continue;
    }
    testCount[curr] = 1
}

print(testCount)
```

I'm working on it in order to have something like:

```
test.map_duplicate() or map_duplicate(test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend SequenceType to have a function freq which does exactly what you need here.

```
extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element: Hashable {
    func freq() -> [Self.Generator.Element: Int] {
        return reduce([:]) { (var accu: [Self.Generator.Element: Int], element) in
            accu[element] = accu[element]?.successor() ?? 1
            return accu
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {

    func mergeDuplicates() -> [Element: Int] {
        var result = [Element: Int]()

        self.forEach({ result[$0] = result[$0] ?? 0 + 1 })

        return result
    }

}

var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,9,3,3,9,9,9]

let testCount = test.mergeDuplicates()

print(testCount)
```

The code above provides an extension to any `Array` type that holds `Hashable` elements (anything else is not eligible to be the key of a dictionary).  Method `mergeDuplicates` produces the dictionary you want.  In its implementation, `forEach()` executes a closure over every element in the array (this is typically more straightforward and transparent alternative to old-fashioned for-loop).  Then on each iteration we check whether there is already existing value in the dictionary with a running count (and use nil-coalescing operator `??` to handle cases when a particular value was not yet met before, hence it's zero).  Then increment, and store (back) into the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! A small bug though. self.forEach{ result[$0] = (result[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }

Answer (score 0):

```
var countForNumber = 0

for number in test {
    test.forEach({ if number == $0 { countForNumber++ } })
    testCount[number] = countForNumber
    countForNumber = 0
}
```